# ui-options и инцилизация параметров

Tags: javascript, angularjs

есть граффики

```
 <div ui-jq="easyPieChart" ui-refresh="minutes5" ng-init="minutes5" ui-options="{
                             easing: 'easeOutBounce',
                             barColor: '{{app.color.accent}}',
                             trackColor: '#f5f5f5',
                             scaleColor: '#eaeaea',
                             lineCap: 'square',
                             lineWidth: 5,
                             size: 120,
                             animate: 1000,
                             percent: {{minutes5}}
                             }">
                            </div>
```

Даже всё работает но вот при загрузке срабатывает ошибка 
`"Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '}' not a primary expression at column 495 of the expression [[{
                                 easing: 'easeOutBounce',
                                 barColor: '#695f56',
                                 trackColor: '#f5f5f5',
                                 scaleColor: '#eaeaea',
                                 lineCap: 'square',
                                 lineWidth: 5,
                                 size: 120,
                                 animate: 1000,
                                 percent: 
                                 }]] starting at [}]].`

Эта касаймо для ЛЮБОЙ диаграммы что я указываю. если пишу ng-init="minutes5=0" то графики всегда в 0. Но если значение фиксированное то проблем нет. Как решить проблему данную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка данная решается просто вот конечный код не каких ошибок нет

```
ui-options="{
                             easing: 'easeOutBounce',
                             barColor: '{{app.color.accent}}',
                             trackColor: '#f5f5f5',
                             scaleColor: '#eaeaea',
                             lineCap: 'square',
                             lineWidth: 5,
                             size: 120,
                             animate: 1000,
                             percent: '{{minutes5}}'
                             }"
```

То есть брать в скобки данные что бы при инициализации было пустое значение.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> barColor: '{{app.color.accent}}',
> ```
>
> ```
> percent: {{minutes5}}
> ```

Вероятно, тут не нужны фигурные скобки.